# Remove Strings from two patterns/characters with sed

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, files, text-formatting

I want to remove the string inside two patterns/characters, so if I have a file containing `"% Blah blah %` i want to remove `Blah blah` as well as the pattern character in this case it will be `% %`. so after deleting the string all thats left will be `""`.
Im doing: `sed -E '/"%,%"/d' file` but that doesn't seem to delete the string.
Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: May `% Blah blah %` extend across a line boundary?

Comment: @steeldriver you can assume % blah blash % is on one line

Comment: The start pattern and the last are the same `%`?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity the format is something like "% hello %" or "% hello world %"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `% Blah blah %` cannot break across a line boundary, and that `Blah blah` does not itself contain `%`, then you can use

```
sed 's/%[^%]*%//' file
```

Add the `g` modifier if you need to replace more than one instance of the pattern per line.